# How to override css styles in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working in a wordpress site. I have been using the "custom code plugin" in order to add css style to the site, until the moment it worked for everthing.

But I found that some elements are no using the style I define for them. Those elements are using the predefined by wordpress.

I have this element:

[image]

This is the html code of the element

[image]

The css class **generic-button**  is created by wordpress and defined the element's style.  I tried to override with this  css class:

```
.action div.generic-button{
   animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
  align-content: unset;
align-items: unset;
align-self: unset;
animation: unset;
appearance: unset;
backface-visibility: unset;
background-blend-mode: unset;
background: unset;
binding: unset;
block-size: unset;
border-block-end: unset;
border-block-start: unset;
border-collapse: unset;
border-inline-end: unset;
border-inline-start: unset;
border-radius: unset;
border-spacing: unset;
border: unset;
bottom: unset;
box-align: unset;
box-decoration-break: unset;
box-direction: unset;
box-flex: unset;
box-ordinal-group: unset;
box-orient: unset;
box-pack: unset;
box-shadow: unset;
box-sizing: unset;
caption-side: unset;
clear: unset;
clip-path: unset;
clip-rule: unset;
clip: unset;
color-adjust: unset;
color-interpolation-filters: unset;
color-interpolation: unset;
color: unset;
column-fill: unset;
column-gap: unset;
column-rule: unset;
columns: unset;
content: unset;
control-character-visibility: unset;
counter-increment: unset;
counter-reset: unset;
cursor: unset;
display: unset;
dominant-baseline: unset;
empty-cells: unset;
fill-opacity: unset;
fill-rule: unset;
fill: unset;
filter: unset;
flex-flow: unset;
flex: unset;
float-edge: unset;
float: unset;
flood-color: unset;
flood-opacity: unset;
font-family: unset;
font-feature-settings: unset;
font-kerning: unset;
font-language-override: unset;
font-size-adjust: unset;
font-size: unset;
font-stretch: unset;
font-style: oblique;
font-synthesis: unset;
font-variant: unset;
font-weight: unset;
font: ;
force-broken-image-icon: unset;
height: unset;
hyphens: unset;
image-orientation: unset;
image-region: unset;
image-rendering: unset;
ime-mode: unset;
inline-size: unset;
isolation: unset;
justify-content: unset;
justify-items: unset;
justify-self: unset;
left: unset;
letter-spacing: unset;
lighting-color: unset;
line-height: unset;
list-style: unset;
margin-block-end: unset;
margin-block-start: unset;
margin-inline-end: unset;
margin-inline-start: unset;
margin: unset;
marker-offset: unset;
marker: unset;
mask-type: unset;
mask: unset;
max-block-size: unset;
max-height: unset;
max-inline-size: unset;
max-width: unset;
min-block-size: unset;
min-height: unset;
min-inline-size: unset;
min-width: unset;
mix-blend-mode: unset;
object-fit: unset;
object-position: unset;
offset-block-end: unset;
offset-block-start: unset;
offset-inline-end: unset;
offset-inline-start: unset;
opacity: unset;
order: unset;
orient: unset;
outline-offset: unset;
outline-radius: unset;
outline: unset;
overflow: unset;
padding-block-end: unset;
padding-block-start: unset;
padding-inline-end: unset;
padding-inline-start: unset;
padding: unset;
page-break-after: unset;
page-break-before: unset;
page-break-inside: unset;
paint-order: unset;
perspective-origin: unset;
perspective: unset;
pointer-events: unset;
position: unset;
quotes: unset;
resize: unset;
right: unset;
ruby-align: unset;
ruby-position: unset;
scroll-behavior: unset;
scroll-snap-coordinate: unset;
scroll-snap-destination: unset;
scroll-snap-points-x: unset;
scroll-snap-points-y: unset;
scroll-snap-type: unset;
shape-rendering: unset;
stack-sizing: unset;
stop-color: unset;
stop-opacity: unset;
stroke-dasharray: unset;
stroke-dashoffset: unset;
stroke-linecap: unset;
stroke-linejoin: unset;
stroke-miterlimit: unset;
stroke-opacity: unset;
stroke-width: unset;
stroke: unset;
tab-size: unset;
table-layout: unset;
text-align-last: unset;
text-align: unset;
text-anchor: unset;
text-combine-upright: unset;
text-decoration: unset;
text-emphasis-position: unset;
text-emphasis: unset;
text-indent: unset;
text-orientation: unset;
text-overflow: unset;
text-rendering: unset;
text-shadow: unset;
text-size-adjust: unset;
text-transform: unset;
top: unset;
transform-origin: unset;
transform-style: unset;
transform: unset;
transition: unset;
user-focus: unset;
user-input: unset;
user-modify: unset;
user-select: unset;
vector-effect: unset;
vertical-align: unset;
visibility: unset;
white-space: unset;
width: unset;
will-change: unset;
window-dragging: unset;
word-break: unset;
word-spacing: unset;
word-wrap: unset;
writing-mode: unset;
z-index: unset;
    /* basic modern patch */
    all: initial; !important;
    all: unset;

   color:#28B463 !important;

font-weight:600 !important;
font-size:large !important;
  margin-right:1em !important;

 }
```

But I cant remove the properties of the predefined class by wordpress.

The "button" should look like this:

[image]

what can i do to override css styles?

Edit:

This is the styles I need to override

[image]

The "div.generic-button a" elements is giving me issues

Comment: Please show us the css that you are trying to override. (1) its possible your selector is less specific than the one you are trying to override, so it would take precedence. (2) You shouldn't need to override *everything* - only set the styles that need to be overridden

Comment: Your selector is targeting an element with a class of `.generic-button`. The selector in the screenshot is targeting an anchor element **inside** of an element with a class of `.generic-button`. Some properties will be inherited by the child anchor but most will not. Target the anchor in your selector as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is targeting an element with a class of `.generic-button` not an anchor element that is a child of an element with `.generic-button` like the selector in the screenshot is.

It looks like you're mostly looking to get rid of the background and borders. Try something like this (make additional adjustments as needed).

```
div.generic-button a {
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: large;
  color: #28B463;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}
```

Make sure the new style is placed after the original so it will override it. If you are not able to do that then increase the element's specificity in some way.

Comment: Looks like there is another selector that's greyish which might seem commented out at first glance. Shouldn't it be `div.generic-button a, .comment-reply-link { }` ?

Comment: No. `div.generic-button a, .comment-reply-link {}` is two selectors combined into one with the comma `,`. The comma allows you to simplify your CSS. Instead of `h1 { color: blue; }` and `h2 { color: blue; }` and `h3 { color: blue; }` you can do `h1, h2, h3 { color: blue; }`. Now you don't have to change the color in three places. The text is grayed out because that particular selector it is **not** being applied to the currently inspected element.

Comment: I didn't notice that many selectors above them are grayed out as well, my bad!